# How to lower volume on Skype (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype

I am using Skype on Windows 10, and there are no menus at the top (as shown in the image) and there is nowhere to click to lower volume when in a call. What I wish to do is to make the sound from that call lower, while keeping other sound from other apps as normal. Is this possible? I remember that before, there was a connection bar you could click when in a call to adjust volume, but this is no longer there. Also I find it strange that there is no menu, perhaps I have a wrong version of Skype?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click with right mouse button on the Sound icon in system tray and open Volume Mixer. There you can adjust the volume independently for each application.

[image: Windows volume mixer]

Comment: This doesn't have any effect in the current version of Skype for Windows 10.